# timerfd and read

Tags: c++, timer, timeout, epoll

I have application, that periodically (by timer) check some data storage.
Like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// EPOLL & TIMER
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* epoll instance */
    int efd = epoll_create1(EPOLL_CLOEXEC);

    if (efd < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "epoll_create error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct epoll_event ev;
    struct epoll_event events[128];

    /* timer instance */
    int tfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TFD_CLOEXEC);

    struct timespec ts;
    // first expiration in 3. seconds after program start
    ts.tv_sec = 3;
    ts.tv_nsec = 0;

    struct itimerspec new_timeout;
    struct itimerspec old_timeout;

    bzero(&new_timeout, sizeof(new_timeout));
    bzero(&old_timeout, sizeof(old_timeout));

    // value
    new_timeout.it_value = ts;

    // no interval;
    // timer will be armed in epoll_wait event trigger
    new_timeout.it_interval.tv_sec =
    new_timeout.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    // Add the timer descriptor to epoll.
    if (tfd != -1)
    {
        ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLERR /*| EPOLLET*/;
        ev.data.ptr = &tfd;
        epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, tfd, &ev);
    }

    int flags = 0;
    if (timerfd_settime(tfd, flags, &new_timeout, &old_timeout) < 0)
    {
       std::cerr << "timerfd_settime error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }

    int numEvents = 0;
    int timeout = 0;
    bool checkTimer = false;
    while (1)
    {
        checkTimer = false;
        numEvents = epoll_wait(efd, events, 128, timeout);
        if (numEvents > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numEvents; ++i)
            {
                if (events[i].data.ptr == &tfd)
                {
                    std::cout << "timeout" << std::endl;
                    checkTimer = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(numEvents == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "An error occured: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        }

        if (checkTimer)
        {
            /* Check data storage */
            uint64_t value;
            ssize_t readBytes;
            //while ( (readBytes = read(tfd, &value, 8)) > 0)
            //{
            //    std::cout << "\tread: '" << value << "'" << std::endl;
            //}
            itimerspec new_timeout;
            itimerspec old_timeout;
            new_timeout.it_value.tv_sec = rand() % 3 + 1;
            new_timeout.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
            new_timeout.it_interval.tv_sec =
            new_timeout.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
            timerfd_settime(tfd, flags, &new_timeout, &old_timeout);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is simple description of my app.
After each timeout timer need to be rearmed by some value different in each timeout.

Questions are:

1. Is it necessary to add timerfd to epoll (epoll_ctl) with EPOLLET flag?
2. Is it necessary to read timerfd after each timeout?
3. Is it necessary to epoll_wait infinitely (timeout = -1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in one of two modes, edge triggered or level triggered. If you choose the edge triggered route then you must pass `EPOLLET` and do not need to read the `timerfd` after each wakeup. The fact that you receive an event from `epoll` means one or more time outs have fired. Optionally you may read the `timerfd` and it will return the number of time outs that have fired *since you last read it*.

If you choose the level triggered route then you don't need to pass `EPOLLET`, but you *must* read the `timerfd` after each wakeup. If you do not then you will immediately be woken up again until you consume the time out.

You should either pass `-1` to `epoll` as the time out or some positive value. If you pass `0`, like you do in the example, then you will never go to sleep, you'll just spin waiting for the time out to fire. That's almost certainly undesirable behaviour.

Comment: Seems like `read()` is a must in both cases. Without `read()`, in the case of `EPOLLET`, you will not get the next event (until `read()` occur), and without `EPOLLET`, you will continuously receive the event (until `read()` occur).

Answer (score 0):

Answers to the questions:

> 1. Is it necessary to add timerfd to epoll (epoll_ctl) with EPOLLET flag?

No. Adding `EPOLLET` (edge trigger) does changes the behavior of receiving events. Without `EPOLLET`, you'll continuously receive the event from `epoll_wait` related to the `timerfd` until you've `read()` from the `timerfd`. With `EPOLLET`, you'll NOT receive additional events beyond the first one, **even if new expiration occurs**, until you've `read()` from the `timerfd` and a new expiration occur.

> 2. Is it necessary to read timerfd after each timeout?

Yes in order to continue and receive events (only) when new expiration occur (see above). No when periodic timer is not used (single expiration only), and you close the `timerfd` without reading.

> 3. Is it necessary to epoll_wait infinitely (timeout = -1)?

No. You can use `epoll_wait`'s timeout instead of `timerfd`. I personally think it is easier to use `timerfd` than keep calculating the next timeout for `EPOLL`, especially if you expect multiple timeout intervals; keeping tabs on what is your next task when timeout occurs is much easier when it is tied to the specific event what woke up.